# How to add elements in list of integers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, data-structures

Total newbie question--how would I define a function to add multiple elements in a list of, say, six integers?

Answer (score 0):

You can [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) elements into the list...

> list.append(x)
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

This is an Example, from the official Python DEv.

```
>>> a = [66.25, 333, 333, 1, 1234.5]
>>> a.append(333)
>>> a
[66.25, 333, -1, 333, 1, 1234.5, 333]
```